# long polling or just a normal ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, long-polling, polling

I have a php application where i need to check if the user is currently logged in

Actually I run this:

```
$(function(){
        function checkSessionDaemon(){
            $.ajax({
                data: "outputFormat=JSON",
                url: baseUrl+"/user/index/checkSessionDaemon/", //mysql query here
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: false
            }).always(function(data){
                if(data.content.iduser== iduser){
                    //do something or do nothing...
                }
                else{
                    alert('disconnected');
                }


                setTimeout(checkSessionDaemon, 50000);
            });
        }
});
```

it's works, but it is correct? In this script I query my database many times.
long polling could be better?

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you need to constantly make sure they are logged in?  Is this an actual PHP application or is this browser based where you could use session cookies?

Comment: Yes, I need the account is logged only one time. If another one use the same account, the previous  must be disconnected

Comment: it works, so it is ok. 
there are a billion ways to skin a cat, and to answer if it is correct the answer is always 'it depends' 
long polling is always better if you optimize for bandwidth, your way is always better if you optimize for responsiveness. 

anyway, as there is no real problem here that's suitable for solving on stack, i'm voting it down. (imo architectural design decisions are far too complex to be answered in a single forum question)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's useful. My doubt was thinking about performance. By the way I can't understand your downvote. It's a normal question and I only need to know if my method works fine in production (with 30-40 clients)